# Android - Ensuring that photo orientation is preserved when taking photos via Camera Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am building an Android App where the user can take a photo and then it gets saved to a certain file path. I have no problems with using the camera intent and saving the result to a custom file path as well as showing it to the user in an ImageView. However, I've recently encountered a strange behaviour when I was testing it over several devices.

Whenever I take the photo in portrait, I get a landscape result.

Here is the code I use:

```
public void onTakePhoto(View view){


    //camera stuff
    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

    //folder stuff
    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "folderHere");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();

    File image = new File(imagesFolder, timeStamp + ".png");
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    startActivityForResult(imageIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

}
```

This opens the camera and takes 1 shot. After the 1 shot, the user can choose to retry taking the photo. I've found out that for some devices, even if I take the photo portrait, the output turns landscape. I've set the orientation of the activity to portrait.

What I've done so far to get the result, determine the rotation using the Exif File, then rotate it accordingly (as so detailed in a handful of answers to the issue I'm having). However, the problem here is that it takes some time, I get 3-4 seconds of black screen before I get back to my activity where I see it in the ImageView.

Here's the rotation code I used:

File is the file path in String.

```
BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bounds);

BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, opts);
ExifInterface exif = null;

try {
    exif = new ExifInterface(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "exception hit while making exif!", e);
}

String orientString = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
int orientation = orientString != null ? Integer.parseInt(orientString) :  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;

int rotationAngle = 0;
if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) rotationAngle = 90;
if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) rotationAngle = 180;
if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) rotationAngle = 270;

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(rotationAngle, (float) bm.getWidth() / 2, (float) bm.getHeight() / 2);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bounds.outWidth, bounds.outHeight, matrix, true);

FileOutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
    rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
    // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "exception hit while exporting!", e);
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there a reliable way of making sure that the orientation of the camera gets preserved when saving the photo? If the camera is on portrait then the result should be in portrait as well, the same case for landscape.

I've been looking around but I've had little luck. A solution I can think of is maybe we can pass something along with the camera intent, like a rotation constant or something, so that the output doesn't get messed with and we get the orientation we want.

Comment: All Android cameras I've worked with always save the data in width x height as opposed to height x width. It's the EXIF data's job to provide you with the proper orientation. I think your problem is that whatever code you're using to rotate the image is too slow - could you give us a sample of that?

Comment: @npace: The behavior of Android device hardware/firmware with respect to orientation varies. Some devices, like most Nexus devices, save the image rotated based on the device orientation at the time the picture was taken. Other devices, like most Samsung devices, save the image in landscape and set the EXIF header based on the device orientation at the time the picture was taken. Apps can attempt to normalize this, but many do not.

Comment: @npace updated my question.

Comment: @CommonsWare Useful comment. I'd forgotten that some devices save the image in the proper orientation since writing code to handle Samsung's orientation issues hides that bit of sane engineering...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a reliable way of making sure that the orientation of the camera gets preserved when saving the photo?

No.

First, you are delegating the picture taking to a third-party app, one of thousands of possible camera apps. Those developers can do whatever they want.

Second, the underlying cause of this comes from camera hardware and firmware. You have no means of telling some chipset to rotate the image instead of using the EXIF orientation header.

Comment: 1. I am using the native camera application. 2. So there's no reliable way of making sure that the native camera doesn't screw you over with rotation? You'd just have to rely on the output, get the EXIF orientation header, and then rotate as needed?

Comment: @Razgriz: "I am using the native camera application" -- first, there are thousands of Android device models, with hundreds of different camera apps pre-loaded on those. Second, you are *not* using "the native camera application", but instead are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Third-party apps can offer to support this, and the user can choose to use one of those. So, you are integrating with thousands of possible camera apps, and the behavior of each of those will vary, based on what their developers choose to do.

Comment: @Razgriz: "So there's no reliable way of making sure that the native camera doesn't screw you over with rotation?" -- again, you are not using "the native camera". What third-party apps do is up to them. Many of them will simply store whatever the camera APIs give them, and *that* varies by hardware, in terms of image orientation (actual data and EXIF headers). "You'd just have to rely on the output, get the EXIF orientation header, and then rotate as needed?" -- correct. This is no different than if you got the images from arbitrary other sources.

Comment: @Razgriz: [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/EXIFRotater) demonstrates two ways of addressing this: rotating the actual `Bitmap` and rotating the `ImageView`.

Comment: @Razgriz: If you control the server, have the server look at the EXIF header and rotate the image there. If you don't control the server, you might use both techniques: rotate the `ImageView` for display, while in the background you rotate the `Bitmap` as part of your upload process.